# HttpConfiguration is missing MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpconfiguration

I've got error:

```
The Type or Namespace name "HttpConfiguration" is missing
```

Honestly i dont konow what to do now.. I have download all files from server once again and nothing.. Please, help :/

```
namespace Europilka
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
        }
    }
}
```

And code is C#. The error is appearing in lines "(HttpConfiguration config)" and "id = RouteParameter.Optional".

Comment: Please add code and language tag.

Comment: Look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c54556b6-c46d-483f-b847-87ed8a24b656/httpconfiguration-assembly-reference-error) mybe this helps.

Comment: have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795167/httpconfiguration-missing-assembly