# How do I add a Web API component to my MVC 6 app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a newly created MVC 6 app, based on the ASP.NET 5 Web Application template, and I would like to include some Web API functionality in this project. It's easy to add an `API/Controllers` folder, and add [api] controllers there, but I cannot configure Web API, When I try and add the following code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I get a compile error that `HttpConfiguration` is an unknown type. I have tried adding references to web API ( I can't recall which), but showed as errors in my references folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795167/httpconfiguration-missing-assembly

Comment: @SillyVolley That answer involved setting a reference to `System.Web.Http`, which I cannot find anywhere when I try and add a reference. 

Then, a comment suggests installing the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`, and when I do that, the added reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` causes a "Cannot resolve" error.

Comment: Can you post that error?

Comment: Could you include `Startup.cs` from your current project? It will be used by ASP.NET 5 project. Could you include additionally the content of `"dependencies"` part of the `project.json` file? I recommend you to compare your code with the code from [the article](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6).

Answer (score 0):

Too big to comment, so putting it here:

If you create MVC6 application, you can just inherit your Api controller from `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller` and no need for `System.Web.Http.ApiController` since mvc and webapi are getting under one roof.

You can check more in [Migrate Models and Controllers](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfromwebapi2.html) section

Getting started: [WebApi in MVC6](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6)

**Edit**

You can try following steps to resolve `System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration`

1) Add reference to following dependency in `project.json` file (you can add as `Nuget` package also)

```
"dependencies": { 
  ... 
  ... 
  "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3" 
},
```

2) Add reference to `System.Web` from framework assemblies section
That should do following change in "project.json" otherwise do it manually

```
"frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {    //This section will be added
                "System.Web": "4.0.0.0" //This reference will be added
            }
}
```

3) Remove `dnxcore50` under `frameworks` section in `project.json`, since `System.Web` itself not available in `DNX Core 5.0`. It is shown in intellisense also.

```
"frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": { } //Remove this node. Remove comma(,) in above line too!!
},
```

4) Clean and Rebuild solution. Hopefully that should resolve the references.

I have followed these steps in a new MVC 6 application and was able to instantiate `HttpConfiguration` properly just for test inside a controller.

Note: I didn't verified the functionality of the instance and so can't guaranty the functionality since its not in support!!

Hope this help you...

Comment: I already know and have done this. This has no bearing on my problem of `HttpConfiguration` not being a known type in a straight MVC project.